# Processing incoming messages in Applescript via mail rule in Mavericks

Tags: email, applescript, rule

I have a simple auto-reply script, based on examples I have seen here and elsewhere, that is intended to run from a spam-filtering Mail rule. Here's the gist of it:

```
on perform_mail_action(theData)
    tell application "Mail"
        set theMessages to |selectedMessages| of theData
        repeat with theIncomingMessage in theMessages
            set theOriginalSender to sender of theIncomingMessage
            set theOriginalSubject to subject of theIncomingMessage
            set theOriginalContent to content of theIncomingMessage
            set t to ""
            set t to t & "This is an automated response to your message below..."
            set t to t & return & return & "===============================================" & return & return
            set t to t & "Subject:" & theOriginalSubject & return & return & theOriginalContent
            set theReply to make new outgoing message
            tell theReply
                make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients ¬
                    with properties {address:theOriginalSender}
                set sender to "xxx@xxx.net"
                set subject to "RE: your message"
                set content to t
                send
            end tell
            set mailbox of theIncomingMessage to mailbox "Trash"
        end repeat
    end tell
end perform_mail_action
```

I know the rule that invokes this script is firing, because it plays a sound. But nothing is sent, and the incoming message remains in my inbox.

If I remove the first and last lines, and replace the third line with

```
    set theMessages to messages of mailbox "test" of account "iCloud"
```

then it successfully processes all messages in the "test" folder (it sends the reply and deletes the incoming message).

The rule does nothing but play a sound and invoke the script. As noted above, the sound plays. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the first 3 lines (including `set theMessage...`) with:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
   on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
      tell application "Mail"
```

Replace the last line with:

```
   end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Comment: Why end using terms from? I'm not in a using terms from block.

Comment: oops, ignore previous cmment. I missed the first part where I was supposed to insert the using terms from statement....

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Michele Percich's response, despite information available online (e.g., [Introduction to Scripting Mail](http://preserve.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.09/ScriptingMail/index.html)) Mail doesn't seem to run a handler of the form:

```
on perform_mail_action(theData)
```

But it does run the handler if it's written in this form:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
   on perform mail action with messages theSelectedMessages for rule theRule
```